What functions can change zeroes into null values?
I am new to data analysis but I have a project due about weather. I am working with a new set of data (not cleaned yet) and I have noticed that some values were incorrectly entered as zeroes (0) instead of as "null". How can I change the 0 values into null values? I am working in Google sheets for this project and trying to find trends between wind speed and visibility. Thanks!
I have not tried anything as of yet. I was looking for pointers on where to start.

Does IF work?

instead of as "null" Do you literally mean "null'', or just blank. Anyway, sort the data by the relevant column to put the "0" values at the top of the sheet, then highlight and delete (press the delete key) the "0" values.

Use the IF function
Inline with @nneonneo comment. The IF function is a premade function in Google Sheets, which returns values based on a true or false condition.
Try this formula in a new column:
 =IF(A1=0, "", A1)


Reference
IF Function

To help you get started with cleaning your weather data in Google Sheets, especially converting zeroes into NULL values, here’s a simple approach:

Replace Zeroes with Blank Cells (acting as NULL)
In Google Sheets, you can't directly use NULL like in SQL, but you can leave cells blank to represent missing or null values.

Steps:

Select the column (or range of cells) where zeroes are incorrectly entered.
Use "Find and Replace":
Press Ctrl + H (or go to Edit > Find and Replace).
In the "Find" field, type 0.
Leave the "Replace" field blank.
Under options, ensure "Match entire cell contents" is checked.
Click "Replace all."

This will replace all zeroes with blank cells, treating them like missing or NULL values.
